# Content padding with Snap.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, snap.js

I just got one maybe simple question. I use snap.js to create a slidable menu, but how do I add padding to the contant?

Here is the source: http://runnable.com/UoqMXucPORNzAAIH/how-to-create-a-mobile-shelf-using-snap-js-for-javascript

Source project on GitHub: https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/

Here is the code for the content:

```
<div id="content" class="snap-content">
    <div id="toolbar">
        <a href="#" id="open-left"></a>
        <h1>Default</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Here goes the content I guess, but there is no padding -->
</div>
```

I need to have all content in the *#content* to make it slidable with a finger. But I can't get the content to have padding so it looks bad, in my opinion.. If I add padding to *#content* the menu also gets it. Then i tried to add a new `<div>` named *#main* and placed it under *#toolbar* but then the padding is acting like margin for some reason. *#main* had 100% width and padding of 10px. The #toolbar displayed like 100% but showed 100% + 10px (left) + 10px (right) so it adds the scroll and look awful.

How have others solved this?

As you can see in this JSFiddle there is no padding: http://jsfiddle.net/TorchMan/MexXY/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can move all of your contents you mean to new element,
for example:

```
<div id="content" class="snap-content">
    <div id="toolbar">
        <a href="#" id="open-left"></a>
        <h1>Default</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Here goes the content I guess, but there is no padding -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and add style

```
#content-wrapper{
    padding:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MexXY/21/

Comment: Okey, I feel defeated by stupidity or something.. :P I have tried just that with #main (new div with padding) but it didn't worked for me. Now I tried again and it's working. Thanks mate!